# JPA Mapping does't give required output

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I have mapped 2 entities using JPA mapping (one to many)

**PawnMaster.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pawnMater", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<PawnItem> pawnItem;
```

**PawnItem.java**

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PAWN_TICKET_NO", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private PawnMaster pawnMater;
```

In here, when I get an object from pawn master class it doesn't give me a list of pawnItems. The result is,

```
{
"id": 22,
"branch": {
"code": "HAN",
"description": "HANWELLA",
"isBranch": false
},
"pawnItem": [],
}
```

This is the .json object which I get. But it does't have list of pawnItem. Only the type and object paras are there. 
I can't find what is the problem of this and I'm wonder if there is a problem with my mapping or not. 
Please help me. Thank you.

Ok Neil Stockton, Thanks for attention, this is my code which I used to retrieve the object.

```
public Response<PawnMaster> getPawnTicket(final Long pawnTicketNo) {
    LOGGER.info("getPawnTicket");
    final Response<PawnMaster> response = new Response();
    try {
        PawnMaster pawnMaster = (PawnMaster) em.createQuery("SELECT pm FROM PawnMaster pm where pm.id =:pawnTicketNo")
                .setParameter("pawnTicketNo", pawnTicketNo)
                .getSingleResult();
        response.setData(pawnMaster);
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        LOGGER.error("NoResultException Error : " + e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

In here I'm using HQL as the query language. But it the debugging time is shows 2 object. 
[image]

Comment: Put joinColumn in @onetomany too

Comment: I don't want to have a column in PawnMaster table. Because I don't want to have duplicate PawnMasterIds there. Anyway thanks Frank :)

Comment: So that is JSON, and what is the JPA code that retrieved the object? and what fields were populated WHEN it was JPA managed? this is a step called debugging

Comment: so you didnt tell it to retrieve the List field. using "JOIN FETCH" in the query you can do that; there are ample documentation pages on the internet telling how to do that; search

Comment: how about using `FetchType.EAGER` in `@OneToMany` mapping as default fetch type is lazy.

Comment: Problem is I have mapped this as Bidirectional. So that the objects are calling them selves and this is end-up with a diamond problem. So I want to solve that problem and get one object with list of other objects.

Comment: Sagar Kadu Thanks for paying attention. I have tried with your method also. When using FetchType.EAGER also gives me diamond problem.

Comment: bidirectional mapping is just a way of getting one entity from other..you could use unidirectional mapping to get list of pawnItem from PawnMaster..have look at this [https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany]

Comment: @Shamila When using FetchType.EAGER also gives me the diamond problem -> If you happen to use Jackson as JSON serializer then you can use `@JsonIgnore` property on PawnItem:PawnMaster attribute.